# Pagination while Get Variables in URL

Tags: add-on, module, pagination

I've built a plugin that runs on a page & pulls data from a get variable in the URL.  Page URIs look like '/page&foo=bar'.  That's working perfectly.

I've also built pagination into my plugin, since I have some large datasets outputting.  That also works perfectly on it's own.

The problem is that when I have a Get variable in the URL my pagination links don't account for it.  Is there a trick to getting an add-on to recognize Get variables in the URL?  I can provide some example code if needed, but I suspect there's something obvious I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't "something obvious" you're missing, as far as I know. I try and maintain the query string in pagination for Low Search, which ended up doing an obtuse regular expression to find/replace URLs without query strings.

Simplest solution is to not automate it, but use something like `{pagination_url}?{current_query_string}` in your pagination links.